# How to compare two sprite textures in unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, sprite

I have a requirement of comparing two sprite textures for knowing those two sprites belongs to same image or not. Here those textures are loaded from urls. Thanks in advance.

Here is the sample code for getting sprite texture:

```
    WWW imageLink = new WWW(imageUrl);

    var spriteTexture = imageLink.texture;
```

In on of my case same image with two different urls. Once url is loaded, have a requirement of identifying those textures have belongs to same image. Please suggest any idea.

Comment: what happens if you make a simple comparison like if(texture.sprite == urlTexture.sprite)?

Comment: compare pixels with two nested for loops (one for x and inner for loop for y) and use https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Texture2D.GetPixels.html

Comment: It's pretty easy to write a comparator. I gave an example below. I hope it helps.

Answer (score 3):

There is no easy util to compare the two textures, but luckily it's easy to write one. The method of Texture2D.GetPixels() will give you a Color[] array which represents a flattened 2d array of pixel colors. Each row of pixels will be placed one after the other, starting from the bottom to the top. Comparing the two arrays should prove the two textures are identical. I tried this code:

```
private bool CompareTexture (Texture2D first, Texture2D second)
{
    Color[] firstPix = first.GetPixels();
    Color[] secondPix = second.GetPixels();
    if (firstPix.Length!= secondPix.Length)
    {
        return false;
    }
    for (int i= 0;i < firstPix.Length;i++)
    {
        if (firstPix[i] != secondPix[i])
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

With you code, you will simply need to call:

```
WWW imageLink = new WWW(imageUrl1); //first image URL
WWW imageLink2 = new WWW(ImageUrl2); //second image URL

if (CompareTexture(imageLink.texture, imageLink2.texture) {
....
}
```

To compare both textures.

Comment: This will fail in many scenarios such as when the image is smaller, rotated and more. The best solution is to use OpenCV or any other existing image processing API.

Comment: not just that - it will fail if the picture was re-saved in jpg and has slight, non-perceivable difference. Which is good, since we want to make sure the images are completely identical. If you wanted to support rotation, resizing and compression changes it does open the field to a much more robust comparison.